RSpec freezing when starting a nested transaction inside of a thread after upgrading to Rails 7.2
I've upgraded a Rails app to Rails 7.2 and some of my tests are hanging. We have some cases more or less like this that freeze when the nested transaction starts:
context 'error', :transactionless do
  let(:concurrent) do
    Thread.new do
      FlowLead.transaction do
        puts 'inside of the transaction'
      end
    end
  end
  it 'should not hang' do
    puts 'starting outer transaction'
    FlowLead.transaction do
      puts 'starting thread'
      concurrent.join
      puts 'after inner transaction'
    end
  end
end

shared_context 'transactionless' do
    uses_transaction(nil)

    after { DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:deletion) }
end

Output:
Randomized with seed 1461
starting outer transaction
starting thread

There it freezes forever.
I checked the activity in postgres but it doesn't help much:
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
292084  testdb  78482   NULL    10  postgres    /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/bin/rspec   127.0.0.1   NULL    61253   2024-12-16 18:51:36.963283+01   2024-12-16 18:51:37.174001+01   2024-12-16 18:51:37.272498+01   2024-12-16 18:51:37.272507+01   Client  ClientRead  idle in transaction 510729  NULL    NULL    RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1   client backend

I guess this might not be enough to reproduce it but maybe someone can shed some light into why it might happen?
I'm using ruby 3.2 + rails 7.2.2.1 + rspec-rails 7.1.0
Update: the test passes when I switch config.use_transactional_fixtures = true to false in my rspec config, but I'd still like to understand what is causing this issue.

Can you please add the version you upgraded from? This will allow for better tracking of the changes that might have been impactful.

I've upgraded Rails from 6.1.0 and rspec-rails from 4.0.0

I found that switching this config in rspec config.use_transactional_fixtures = true to false, makes the test pass, but I'm not really sure why.

Added some more context, in my application we're using this shared_context, I suspect something changed inside uses_transaction in this rails version and it doesn't work as before.

It seems like the problem has to do with how I was using uses_transaction(nil) to prevent specific tests to be wrapped automatically inside of a transaction.
I've replaced that implementation like this, and this works:
shared_context 'transactionless' do
  self.use_transactional_tests = false

  after { DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:deletion) }
end

Honestly I don't know what changed but this seems like a better documented way of disabling transactions within a test. (see Transactional Tests: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html)

Seems if you are using DatabaseCleaner, RSpec documentation recommends this action: "If you prefer to manage the data yourself, or using another tool like database_cleaner to do it for you, simply tell RSpec to tell Rails not to manage transactions"
